# Query to validate and return true or false

Tags: sql

Hi could anyone help on the below please

If I have a table where the values are as below

```
emp_id          emp Name 
 100              john 
 200              Jenny
 300              jack
 400              san
```

I would like to run a query where emp_id and name are already declared and it should return true when the value is correct
Eg:

```
emp_id : 100 
Emp_name : john
```

is the value declared then the query should return true else false.

Comment: would returning a count of 0 or 1 suffice? `Select count(*) from tablename where emp_ID = 100 and Em_p_name = 'John'`  0 meaning no match 1 meaning match and more than 1 meaning more than 1 match

Comment: Suppose I nned to reuse the query again with a different emp_id and emp_number

Comment: Use query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

This should suffice :

```
SELECT  CASE
            WHEN COUNT(emp_id) > 0 THEN 'TRUE'
            ELSE 'FALSE'
        END
FROM    #tab
WHERE   emp_id = @empID
AND     empName = @empName
```

@empID and @empName are the parameters for `emp_id` and `empName` respectively.

You can see this here ->

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/126ce/1 (*where its returns TRUE based on the values*)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/126ce/2 (*where its returns FALSE based on the values*)